# How to expand/enlarge Text selection in CKEditor using javascript.?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Can anyone tell me how to expand or enlarge the selection in CKEditor.

I can get the selection using

```
var EditorInstance = CKEDITOR.instances['Editor'];
var selection = EditorInstance.getSelection();
```

but what i want is to enlarge that selection with javascript.

For example this is my selection now

[image]

then i want to expand or enlarge that selection like this

[image]

And this selection may contain tags like bold italic also..
Using javaScript only please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend the [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsISelection) you can use the [`modify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection/modify/) method as long as you're in a modern web browser.  For example, to extend the selection forward by one word, you could do this:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
selection.modify("extend", "forward", "word");
```

You can also specify to extend backward, and you can specify to extend by word, character, line, etc.

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/F2gFV/6/.  I added some style tags (b, i, span) and it seems to work.  Although it does need a slight modification because it only expands in the direction of the selection.  But this should be a good starting point.

Comment: Looks like for IE you use expand() on the TextRange object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536421(v=vs.85).aspx.  Sorry, I don't have IE to test it.

Comment: You could also try using the CKEDITOR API: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dom.range.html#enlarge

Comment: Yes i am using that `enlarge` function of CKEDITOR API, but it selecting whole paragraph i want to select only 2 words is it possible..?